# Maximizing possible value of a function given constraint

Tags: optimization

A few weeks ago I took part in a math competition and had this question through some trial and error I got the correct answer 80 as I didn't have time to use maximization using calculus, is there a way to do this question quickly in a rigorous way:

Find the maximum possible value of $$ 9\sqrt{x}+8\sqrt{y}+5\sqrt{z} $$

where x, y, and z are positive real numbers satisfying  $$ 9x +4y+z=128 $$

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you know about Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: You mean setting partial derivatives equal to each other different by a scale factor of lambda right. I have done such questions with two variables before. I am only 15 so I have not been able to pursue such subjects in calculus 2 class.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, though the description isn't quite right.  That should work quickly in this case.

Comment: I worked it out using Lagrange multipliers. The solution is <64/25, 256/25, 64> which ends up with the correct answer of 80. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: It was my pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

Rename $(x,y,z)$ to $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, and let $(c_1,c_2,c_3)=(9,8,5)$ and $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(9,4,1)$.
By Cauchy-Schwarz:
\begin{align}
\left(\sum_j c_j \sqrt{x_j}\right)^2 
&= \left(\sum_j \frac{c_j}{\sqrt{a_j}} \sqrt{a_j x_j}\right)^2 \\
&\le \left(\sum_j \left(\frac{c_j}{\sqrt{a_j}}\right)^2\right) \left(\sum_j \sqrt{a_j x_j}^2\right)\\
&= \left(\sum_j \frac{c_j^2}{a_j}\right) \left(\sum_j a_j x_j\right)\\
&= \left(\frac{9^2}{9} + \frac{8^2}{4} + \frac{5^2}{1}\right) 128\\
&= 6400,
\end{align}
so
$$\sum_j c_j \sqrt{x_j} \le 80$$